# What is the most efficient way to retrieve records by day and/or month and/or year?

Tags: mysql, date, select, innodb

**What is the most efficient way to select records by day and/or month and/or year?**

```
INT(2) day
INT(2) month
INT(4) year

SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.year=2015
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.month=9 AND table.year=2015
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.day=26 AND table.month=9 AND table.year=2015
```

or

```
DATE   date

SELECT * FROM table WHERE YEAR(table.date)=2015
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(table.date)=9 AND YEAR(table.date)=2015
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.date="2015-09-26"
```

> Note: There also may be situations where the day is searched regardless
>   of the month and year, or the month is search regardless of the day and year.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote, downvote, accept answers if appropriate. Even feedback such as "this is junk and makes no sense". We use that  feedback, and cheers us on to help the next guy, regardless of what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one could drag depending on indexes or composites (note plural). It is quite possible that in trying to be clever, it is slower. The composite widths are not exactly leaner than a date datatype sizing that has it all baked in @3 bytes.

Unless your query is "give me the first day of every month regardless of year and month"

So, I am with #2 for performance. You need to judge performance not just on the queries above, but overall performance (think excessive composites required and their width, even if relatively lean) impact on inserts/updates.

But even so, even just focusing on your queries, 3 bytes is smaller than 8 (or 12 that most people would likely use). Note, we are saying `Date`, not `Datetime`.

Plus you get all the benefits of date functions, without writing your own.

Answer (score 1):

The more efficient way is the first method.  *BUT* you should use native date formats, so that precludes the first method.

So, the best method is:

```
select * from table where table.date >= '2015-01-01' and table.date < '2016-01-01';
select * from table where table.date >= '2015-09-01' and table.date < '2015-10-01';
select * from table where table.date >= '2015-09-26' and table.date < '2016-09-27';
```

The last condition might be able to use `=`, if the date has no time component.